# Presto SQL - Fill in missing values within range with 0

Tags: sql, presto

Here is the initial table:

```
id range val
1  -4.   2
1  -2.   1
1. 1.    1
1  3.    2
1  4.    1
2. -1.   1
2. 0.    1
2. 1.    1
```

Updated Table:

```
id range val
1  -4.   2
1. -3.   0
1  -2.   1
1. -1.   0
1. 0.    0
1. 1.    1
1. 2.    0
1  3.    2
1  4.    1
2. -1.   1
2. 0.    1
2. 1.    1
2. 2.    0
2  3.    0
2  4.    0
```

Desired Logic:

- Each `id` will have some range.
- For each `id`, the lower end of the range will be different but the upper end will be the max max value in the entire table.
- For any missing values within that id's updated range, it will be imputed with 0

I am no SQL wiz so i'm a bit lost. Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if anything is confusing about the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If for each range value, you have at least one value, then I think you want:

```
select i.id, t.range, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct range from t where range > 0) r left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and t.range = r.range
union all
select id, range, value
from t
where range <= 0;
```

How does this work?  The first subquery generates all combinations of the ids and range values, where the range value is greater than 0.  It does this using a Cartesian product of the distinct `id` and `range` values.

The `LEFT JOIN` then brings in the existing data.  And the final subquery brings in the detritus -- the values less than 0.

Comment: I'll definitely try this. For something who doesn't a ton of SQL experience, can you explain the logic in your code? I think itd be helpful to others as well.

Comment: should it be `t.range = r.range` instead?